# Add my php.ini file from my localhost to Plesk 12.0.18 for Windows

Tags: php, plesk

I have tried a billion options about this issue and spent loads of time with godaddy's support but it seems like there is no answer anywhere on internet. If you check my phpinfo http://goliax.com/phpinfo.php you will see what does it say about the location of the php.ini in use but I have no access to any such location. Godaddy fail to provide me with RDC (remote desktop connection) which I read was another way to access the file. The only way to change something on the php.ini file in use in plesk is through an option in plesk itself and it does not even work the way it is expected.

Comment: *I have tried a billion options* Have you tried to contacting your hosting? If yes what did they tell you to do?

Comment: Yes Godaddy is my hosting provider. At first they tried to hide the fact that they have issues providing RDC to users but after multiple calls they admit they have "technical difficulties" with this and they are not sure when can they fix the issue. This was months ago and they also keep throwing the ball at Plesk all the time and Plesk throws it back at Godaddy... It is an amazing magic circle with a dead end :D

Comment: On top I paid someone months ago to develop code for rotating images based on their EXIF orientation and as it turned out if I can not change this (and I can not) in php.ini settings the code will never be in use on my website :( Do you know how few websites on internet have this? Now I see why :(

Comment: if Godaddy won't help you fixing the problem with php.ini, I suggest you to go to another hosting where you can make changes to PHP.ini without problems, I don't know wich hosting it can be because I'm using VPS instead of shared hostings.

Comment: I am on VPS as well and you are suggesting the same thing one of my developers suggested. The thing is though that I am coming from another provider and trust me if they can handle php.ini access they will be unable to deal with a bunch of other serious issues so wether I like it or not I am afraid I have to stick with Godaddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can place `httpdocs/.user.ini` file with content like:

```
[PHP]
max_input_time=120
open_basedir="C:/Inetpub/vhosts/domain.win2012.tld\;C:\Windows\Temp\"
post_max_size=16M
short_open_tag=off
upload_max_filesize=16M
```

For additional domains you should place `.user.ini` inside of domain's web root like:

```
.
..
httpdocs/ <-- this is web root of subscription
addon-domain.com/ <-- this is web root of addon domain inside subscription
```

Pay attention that only "per directory" PHP directives will has effect, you can found more information in PHP docs for php.ini levels.

Also, in plesk domain's PHP settings there are additional directives(they will be placed in Windows registry):

[image: plesk additional php ini directives]

Unfortunately, in Plesk 12.0 you can't change **system** level php.ini settings via Plesk UI.

Since **Plesk 12.5** you can change all php.ini UI:
[image: plesk change system php.ini]

Comment: I am afraid my Plesk is version 12.0.18 and I have tried the mentioned options above none of which is working :( I will find out how can I upgrade Plesk and if it is going to cause major destruction to my website if I simply upgrade it like the upgrade of the php version did.

Comment: Installing Plesk Onyx Version 17.0.17 right now and no idea what it is so pray with me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg. After upgrading Plesk's version (thing which I thought happens automatically as a few times when I have logged in there is a message that Plesk has been upgraded) I managed to find exactly where is the full php.ini from your second picture. Now I can happily change the settings responsible for EXIF orientation and apply the code all over the website :) My other question which you also answered is a bit of a puzzler though...